# In WinRT how can I WriteValueWithResultAsync from other functions?

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

C++, WinRT, VS2017, Win10

In my C++ MFC app I have put C++/WinRT code into a function to find my Bluetooth LE device, create a device object, enumerate the Services and their Characteristics, and then save the txChacteristic to a characteristic object.

While still in that function, where the txChacteristic is still in scope, I can write a value with

```
auto status = co_await txCharacteristic.WriteValueWithResultAsync(writer.DetachBuffer(),
        winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile::GattWriteOption::WriteWithoutResponse);
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out a way to make a characteristic object public so that it is available for writes from other functions.

I have tried to make the txChacteristic object static and then reference it in another function but it shows as "undefined" in that other function.

Is there a way to make an empty characteristic object outside the function and then copy into it later?  Or create an array or vector of this object type to copy into?

Does anyone have a suggestion on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to write from another function.  In the public scope I initiated empty characteristic objects like this:

```
winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile::GattCharacteristic pubTxCharacteristic = nullptr;
winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile::GattCharacteristic pubRxCharacteristic = nullptr;
```

In the OpenDevice function where we actually create the rx and txCharacteristic objects I transfered the objects to the public ones like this:

```
pubTxCharacteristic = txCharacteristic;
pubRxCharacteristic = rxCharacteristic;
```

When setting up the callback to the Rx characteristic I needed to also use the public object to keep the callback in public awareness.

```
GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue cccdValue = GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue::None;
if ((pubRxCharacteristic.CharacteristicProperties() & GattCharacteristicProperties::Notify) != GattCharacteristicProperties::None)
{
    cccdValue = GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue::Notify;
}
GattCommunicationStatus comStatus = co_await pubRxCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(cccdValue);
event_token etValueChangeToken;
etValueChangeToken = pubRxCharacteristic.ValueChanged([](GattCharacteristic const& charateristic,
    GattValueChangedEventArgs const& args)
{
    DataReader reader = DataReader::FromBuffer(args.CharacteristicValue());
    //... calback code here
}
```

While still in this OpenDevice function that created the characteristic objects I used the new public objects in the original writes like this:

auto status = co_await pubTxCharacteristic.WriteValueWithResultAsync(writer.DetachBuffer(),
winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile::GattWriteOption::WriteWithoutResponse);
if (status.Status() != GattCommunicationStatus::Success){}

In the other Test function, however, (still in the same .cpp as the OpenDevice function) the compiler would not allow the same syntax to write. It would not allow the co_await and the Status() referred to a different enumeration.
Here is where it stands as of now:

```
auto status = ubTxCharacteristic.WriteValueWithResultAsync(writer.DetachBuffer(),
        winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile::GattWriteOption::WriteWithoutResponse);
        
if (status.Status() == winrt::Windows::Foundation::AsyncStatus::Error) {}
```

The write is successful and the callback shows the reply from the device.

Just out of curiosity, however, does anybody have a guess as to why in one function the auto status = co_await pubTxCharacteristic.WriteValueWithResultAsync would have the status.Status() as a GattCommunicationStatus and the same call in a different function but in the same cpp (without the co_await) has the statue.Status() as a winrt::Windows::Foundation::AsyncStatus enumeration?

I mean, its working, but I'm just curious why this would change.

Comment: Asynchronous functions return `IAsyncAction`/`IAsyncOperation<>`. C++/WinRT provides adapters for those so that they can be used with the `co_await` operator. Note that the former are returned potentially before the function has run to completion, and the `AsyncStatus` you get represents the state of execution, not the actual result. A bit more background: [C++ coroutines: Getting started with awaitable objects](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191209-00/?p=103195) provides a good introduction.

Comment: But both of these calls use the WriteValueWithResultAsync which, theoretically, return the IAsyncAction.  The only difference is that one call in in the function that originally created the device object and others while the other call is from a separate function.  And yet, in the call from the separate function, if I try to use co_await, the intellisense gives me the error that 
    class <std::experimental::coroutine_traits> has no member "promise_type"
and if I try to compile I get the error E0135 with the same description.  Why the different behavior for the same command line?

Answer (score 0):

As for the question posed at the end of my original question, @IInspectable was correct about the IAsyncAction it was just that I was not looking at the cause of the problem.

As it turns out:

The OpenDevice function mentioned in the post as the function that created the device, services, and characteristics objects was:

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction OpenDevice(unsigned long long deviceAddress){}
```

while the other function was bool return ***bool WriteCommand()*** and that was the difference.

I changed the other function to

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction WriteCommend()
```

and that solved the 2nd part of the problem.